# Force unwrap error using the Scripting Bridge with Chrome

Tags: swift, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm trying out Apple's Scripting Bridge to interact with Google Chrome. I've started with the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24147285

I have created `.h` file by using `sdef` and `sdp` commands.

I have included the file and also created the bridging header and imported chrome's header file in bridging header. But the problem is with using the header in Swift. The code is old and Swift has changed a lot.

My Swift file:

```
import Cocoa
import ScriptingBridge


var chromeObject = SBApplication.init(bundleIdentifier: "com.google.Chrome")! as AnyObject

print(chromeObject.closeable)
```

I'm getting an error saying

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Is Chrome installed?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes

Comment: @JoshCaswell The only command which works is `chromeObject.activate()`

Comment: @psh The thing with using `ScriptingBridge` is that the documentation is not very expressive. So that's why you are not getting. Are you sure you wanna continue using `ScriptingBridge` instead of directly using `AppleScript`? It will be easy once you get how it works but it gets tiresome if you are working with iTunes.sdef which has so many interfaces.

Comment: @SkrewEverything I don't know why but I'm not at all comfortable working with AppleScript. I just want to do it in Swift. Please help me!

Comment: It's highly recommended to use `AppleScriptObjC`. It makes things a lot easier.

Comment: @vadian I don't know obj-c and I didn't find any tutorial. That's why I'm using `ScriptingBridge`. The explanation given by @SkrewEverything solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SBApplication` returns Application object. You can see different `interface`s in `.h` file.

```
@interface ChromeApplication : SBApplication
@interface ChromeWindow : SBObject <ChromeGenericMethods>
@interface ChromeApplication (ChromiumSuite)
@interface ChromeTab : SBObject <ChromeGenericMethods>
@interface ChromeBookmarkFolder : SBObject <ChromeGenericMethods>
@interface ChromeBookmarkItem : SBObject <ChromeGenericMethods>
```

So, `SBApplication` returns you `ChromeApplication`. You can call any properties defined inside `ChromeApplication`. Try it yourself. You won't get any error.

The problem is you are calling `closeable` which is part of `ChromeWindow`.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW2):

> **AppleScript and Objects**
>
> AppleScript is an object-oriented language. When you write, compile,
>   and execute scripts, everything you work with is an object. An object
>   is an instantiation of a class definition, which can include
>   properties and actions. AppleScript defines classes for the objects
>   you most commonly work with, starting with the top-level script
>   object, which is the overall script you are working in.
>
> ..............
>
> .....................

and the main thing,

> **What Is in a Script Object**
>
> When you enter AppleScript statements in
>   script window in Script Editor, you are working in a top-level script
>   object. All script object definitions follow the same syntax, except
>   that a top-level script object does not have statements marking its
>   beginning and end.
>
> A script object can contain the following:
>
> Property definitions (optional): A property is a labeled container in
>   which to store a value.
>
> An explicit run handler (optional): A run handler contains statements
>   AppleScript executes when the script is run. (For more information,
>   see run Handlers.)
>
> An implicit run handler (optional): An implicit run handler consists
>   of any statements outside of any contained handlers or script objects.
>
> Additional handlers (optional): A handler is the equivalent of a
>   subroutine. (For details, see About Handlers.)
>
> ***Additional script objects (optional): A script object can contain
>   nested script objects, each of which is defined just like a top-level
>   script object, except that a nested script object is bracketed with
>   statements that mark its beginning and end. (For details, see Script
>   Objects.)***

So, in simple terms, `Application` is an object which contains `Window` which is an object which contains `Tab` object.....

You need to retrieve `Window` object/element from `Application` to use `closeable`.

You should have `SBElementArray` in every `interface`. You need to get that.

Example,

```
// The application's top-level scripting object.
@interface ChromeApplication : SBApplication

- (SBElementArray<ChromeWindow *> *) windows;

@property (copy, readonly) NSString *name;  // The name of the application.
@property (readonly) BOOL frontmost;  // Is this the frontmost (active) application?
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *version;  // The version of the application.

- (void) open:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)x;  // Open a document.
- (void) quit;  // Quit the application.
- (BOOL) exists:(id)x;  // Verify if an object exists.

@end
```

You should retrieve `- (SBElementArray<ChromeWindow *> *) windows;` to use `closable`. Again in windows you have tabs array, etc.

For example, In AppleScript to get URL and title of every tabs:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"

    set a to ""
    repeat with w in windows
        repeat with t in tab in w  // Getting tab object from window
            set a to a & linefeed & title of t & " -URL: " & URL of t
        end repeat
    end repeat

end tell
```

The equivalent in Swift would be:

```
import Cocoa
import ScriptingBridge


var chromeObject: AnyObject = SBApplication.init(bundleIdentifier: "com.google.Chrome")!

var f = chromeObject.windows() // get the windows from application
for i in f!
{
    var t = (i as AnyObject).tabs() // get the tabs from windows
    for j in t!
    {
        print(((j as AnyObject).title as String) + " -URL: " + ((j as AnyObject).url as String))
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The Apple documentation you cite describes how the AppleScript *language* works. AS defines a number of standard built-in datatypes (strings, lists, etc) and supports a sort of prototype-based OOP via script objects. Whereas its Apple event bridge works *totally differently*: application automation is **not** OOP, it's RPC plus simple first-class relational *queries*. (ASLG is worse than useless at explaining this; Dr Cook's [AppleScript paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2006/ashopl.pdf) is much better. SB makes quite a cock of it too, hence the advice to stick with AS if you can.)

Answer (score -2):

From the documentation for [`SBApplication.init?(bundleIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scriptingbridge/sbapplication/1424009-init):

> ### Return Value
>
> An initialized shared instance of an `SBApplication` subclass that represents a target application with the bundle identifier of `ident`. Returns `nil` if no such application can be found or if the application does not have a scripting interface.

You should check that the `init` method returns an instance before force unwrapping, like:

```
if let chromeObject = SBApplication.init(bundleIdentifier: "com.google.Chrome") as? AnyObject {
    print(chromeObject.closeable)
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem is at `chromeObject.closeable`. It always returns `nil`. But when I try in `Obj-c`, it's working fine with some warnings.

Comment: When you print you get that error? If you have Objective C code that works, why don't you post that? And maybe we can help you translate it to Swift?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. @SkrewEverything solved my problem.